# Read firefox passwords: System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, firefox, passwords, mozilla

I have this funtion, and i get this exception:

> "System.ArgumentNullException: The value cannot be null, name of parameter: ptr in System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(IntPtr ptr, Type t)"

Here is my code:

```
private const string ffFolderName = @"\Mozilla Firefox\";

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllFilePath);
static IntPtr NSS3;

[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate long DLLFunctionDelegate(string configdir);

public static int PK11SDR_Decrypt(ref TSECItem data, ref TSECItem result, int cx)
{
            IntPtr pProc = GetProcAddress(NSS3, "PK11SDR_Decrypt");
            DLLFunctionDelegate5 dll = (DLLFunctionDelegate5)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, typeof(DLLFunctionDelegate5));
            return dll(ref data, ref result, cx);
}

public static long NSS_Init(string configdir)
{

            var mozillaPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + ffFolderName;
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(mozillaPath))
                mozillaPath = @"C:\\Program Files\\" + ffFolderName;
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(mozillaPath))
                throw new Exception("Firefox folder not found");

            LoadLibrary(mozillaPath + "mozglue.dll");
            NSS3 = LoadLibrary(mozillaPath + "nss3.dll");
            IntPtr pProc = GetProcAddress(NSS3, "NSS_Init");

            // Below throws the exception
            DLLFunctionDelegate dll = (DLLFunctionDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, typeof(DLLFunctionDelegate)); 
            return dll(configdir);
}
```

I really dont get it, when I debug, it throws an **exception before the return** on the function "NSS_Init", and the pProc variable have the value of "**0x00000000**", I don't know if it's supposed to get this value, and if it is, how can I solve this?

***Thank's to all of you.***

Comment: Is the pointer in NSS3 valid?

Comment: how i can check that? I've checked all the files and they exist

Comment: Of course you want to extract the firefox passwords for a good cause, right?

Comment: I want to save all my passwords to a txt file and put in a extern drive, some friends told me about this way to do it, because saving passwords on browsers are unsafe.

Comment: And i will encrypt the file with my own encryption method, thats why.

Comment: @BarrosKing - In this case you can just go to the Firefox settings and export the passwords (click on the 3... menu), they will be written in readable form.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I know, but i want to do it, i've already done with chrome, and its working well, and just need to do with firefox to, to mesh the both files in one, and crypt with my method and turn into .encbk file, and thats alrerady done, just need to solve this Exception

Comment: Its for personal use only btw

Comment: @BarrosKing The IntPtr (NSS3) is valid if its int value isn't zero.
You might also query `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` to check if loadind the dll succeeded

Comment: @BarrosKing I get only zeropointers (i.e. invalid module handles) for the two LoadLibray calls if i run your code on my machine locally.

Comment: @BarrosKing I could get it to work if i compile to x86 and also load Firefox x86 dlls, Then all 3 IntPtr are non zero.